# How to call method correctly: Messages_SearchGlobal in WTelegram

Tags: wtelegramclient

I use this in my WPF project but always return 0.
var messages = await _client.Messages_SearchGlobal(Search.Text, filter, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it worked; I obtained many messages:

```
var res = await client.Messages_SearchGlobal("test", null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);
```

Your `filter` value must be wrong.

Comment: var filter = new TL.InputMessagesFilterContacts();

Comment: as I understand it, InputMessagesFilterContacts is to search messages which contain an attached "contact" that someone shared with you.

Comment: Yes it is, I didn't figure it out right away.